# Troubleshooting direct sandwich ELISA

Tags: assay-development, elisa

I am validating an ELISA measuring A1c (also called glycated hemoglobin; target for humans) for use in another species. It is a direct sandwich assay. The standard and my sample (whole blood) were both serially diluted twofold.

I am wondering if anybody can help diagnose what I am seeing in my parallelism graph. As you can see, the curves are near inverse of each other (linearity R2 = -0.91). Since it is a direct assay, I would of course expect this correlation to be positive.

[image]

I have gone over my plate map and how I set up my dilution rack a hundred times in my head, and I am quite certain that I did load my plate in the correct sequence as my plate map - ie, having both standard and sample increase in concentration down their respective column. Is there any other possibility (besides me incorrectly loading my plate according to my map) that could cause this "perfectly incorrect" parallelism correlation?

I would love to be proved wrong and find out that it was indeed my error in loading - but I'm pretty sure I loaded it correctly...so I just wanted to check if there was any biological answer to this (matrix effect?)

I plan to run another plate tomorrow to check- but just wanted to ask.

Thank you!

Comment: It might be that there is a molecule present in your whole blood samples that masks your target epitope. Diluting the sample would also dilute the masking. But this is only one possible explanation, I guess there are more variables to consider to find a complete solution.